# Rock-paper-scissors console implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, game, rock-paper-scissors

How can I optimize this code? I want to use more C++11 features.

game_control.h

```
#ifndef GAME_CONTROL_H
#define GAME_CONTROL_H

#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

class Game
{
    unsigned int number_of_turns = 0;
    unsigned int user_score = 0, comp_score = 0;
    std::array<std::string, 3> data = {{"ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSOR"}};
    std::string user_name;

  public:
    Game() {};
    ~Game() = default;

    void start_menu();
    void start_game();
    void game_play(unsigned int, unsigned int);
    void exit_game();
};

#endif
```

game_control.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

#include "game_control.h"


void Game::start_menu()
{
    std::cout << "####  ####  ####  #  #   ####  ####  ####  ####  ####\n";
    std::cout << "#  #  #  #  #     # #    #  #  #  #  #  #  #     #  #\n";
    std::cout << "####  #  #  #     ##     ####  ####  ####  ####  ####\n";
    std::cout << "# #   #  #  #     # #    #     #  #  #     #     # # \n";
    std::cout << "#  #  ####  ####  #  #   #     #  #  #     ####  #  #\n";
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "   ####  ####  #  ####  ####  ####  ####\n";
    std::cout << "   #     #     #  #     #     #  #  #  #\n";
    std::cout << "   ####  #     #  ####  ####  #  #  ####\n";
    std::cout << "      #  #     #     #     #  #  #  # # \n";
    std::cout << "   ####  ####  #  ####  ####  ####  #  #\n";
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    unsigned int selection;
    x:
    std::cout << "\tPress\n";
    std::cout << "\t1 to Enter\n";
    std::cout << "\t2 to Exit\n";
    std::cin >> selection;
    std::cin.clear();

    switch(selection)
    {
        case 1: start_game();
                break;
        case 2: exit_game();
                break;
        default: std::cout << "-------Enter valid choice--------\n";
                 goto x;
                 break;
    }
}

void Game::exit_game()
{
    std::cout << "Thanks for playing!!\n";
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void Game::start_game()
{
    std::cout << "\nEnter your name\n";
    //std::getline(std::cin, user_name);
    std::cin >> user_name;
    std::cin.clear();

    std::cout << "Enter number of turns for you want to play\n";
    std::cin >> number_of_turns;
    std::cin.clear();

    while (number_of_turns--)
    {
        unsigned int user_choice, comp_choice;
        std::cout << "\nEnter your choice\n";
        y:
        std::cout << "\nPress\n";
        std::cout << "1 for ROCK\t2 for PAPER\t3 for SCISSOR\n";
        std::cin >> user_choice;
        if (user_choice > 3)
        {
            std::cout << "\n---------Please enter valid choice------------\n";
            goto y;
        }
        user_choice--;
        std::cin.clear();

        srand(time(0));
        comp_choice = rand() % 3 + 1;

        game_play(user_choice, comp_choice);
        std::cout << "The score is\t";
        std::cout << user_name << " = " << user_score;
        std::cout << "\tComputer = " << comp_score << "\n";
    }
    exit_game();
}

void Game::game_play(unsigned int user_choice, unsigned int comp_choice)
{
    //User = Rock
    if (user_choice == 0)
    {
        if (comp_choice == 1) // Computer = Paper
        {
            std::cout << "\n";
            std::cout << user_name << " chooses " << data[user_choice];
            std::cout << " and Computer chooses " << data[comp_choice] << "\n";
            std::cout << "----Computer Wins!!----\n";
            comp_score++;
        }
        else if (comp_choice == 2) // Computer = Scissor
        {
            std::cout << "\n";
            std::cout << user_name << " chooses " << data[user_choice];
            std::cout << " and Computer chooses " << data[comp_choice] << "\n";
            std::cout << "----" << user_name << " Wins!!----\n";
            user_score++;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "\n";
            std::cout << "Both " << user_name << " and Computer chooses ROCK\n";
        }
    }

    //User = Paper
    if (user_choice == 1)
    {
        if (comp_choice == 0) // Computer = Rock
        {
            std::cout << "\n";
            std::cout << user_name << " chooses " << data[user_choice];
            std::cout << " and Computer chooses " << data[comp_choice] << "\n";
            std::cout << "----" << user_name << " Wins!!----\n";
            user_score++;
        }
        else if (comp_choice == 2) // Computer = Scissor
        {
            std::cout << "\n";
            std::cout << user_name << " chooses " << data[user_choice];
            std::cout << " and Computer chooses " << data[comp_choice] << "\n";
            std::cout << "-----Computer Wins!!-----\n";
            comp_score++;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "\n";
            std::cout << "Both " << user_name << " and Computer chooses PAPER\n";
        }
    }

    //User = Scissor
    if (user_choice == 2)
    {
        if (comp_choice == 0) // Computer = Rock
        {
            std::cout << "\n";
            std::cout << user_name << " chooses " << data[user_choice];
            std::cout << " and Computer chooses " << data[comp_choice] << "\n";
            std::cout << "----Computer Wins!!-----\n";
            comp_score++;
        }
        else if (comp_choice == 1) // Computer = Paper
        {
            std::cout << "\n";
            std::cout << user_name << " chooses " << data[user_choice];
            std::cout << " and Computer chooses " << data[comp_choice] << "\n";
            std::cout << "----" << user_name << " Wins!!----\n";
            user_score++;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "\n";
            std::cout << "Both " << user_name << " and Computer chooses SCISSOR\n";
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "game_control.h"

int main()
{
    Game game;
    game.start_menu();
    game.start_game();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it work as intended?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll go through your code and give comments on some chunks of it. Horizontal lines separate the discussion of different chunks.

---

```
    Game() {};
    ~Game() = default;
```

1. You define a public constructor which doesn't do anything. Why define it at all? If it's intended to be trivial, and you really want to include it, it's better to explicitly say `Game()=default;`.
2. If you go with the explicitly defined constructor, the trailing semicolon is extraneous.
3. The destructor is similar to point 1: there's no need to explicitly say that it's default, unless you want to modify it like e.g. adding `virtual` keyword to it.

---

```
    std::array<std::string, 3> data = {{"ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSOR"}};
```

The name of this variable is not quite useful. I'd rather name it something like `choice_names`.

---

```
    std::cin >> selection;
    std::cin.clear();

    switch(selection)
```

You do clear error flags when the user enters something not parseable as an `unsigned int`, but you forget to clear the read buffer. Thus, on entry of something other than a valid `unsigned int` (e.g. a letter), your program will hang in infinite loop of requesting a valid choice and re-attempting to read the invalid input. An easy fix could be something like this:

```
if(!std::cin)
{
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

---

```
    x:
...
                 goto x;
```

You use `goto` to make a loop. This is already not a good idea, because the language does supply a set of constructs for looping: `for`, `while`, `do...while`. You should use one of these by default, and only resort to `goto` when no sane use of loops will solve your problem.

Moreover, even if you do use `goto` here, the label is badly named. Instead of `x` I'd name it something like `show_menu`.

---

```
    //std::getline(std::cin, user_name);
    std::cin >> user_name;
    std::cin.clear();
```

Actually using `std::getline` *was* a good idea. And current uncommented code fails to work correctly when the user enters e.g. `Name Surname`: the next extraction `std::cin >> number_of_turns;` fails, and you get `number_of_turns==0`. This is because extraction operator stops on white space. Using `std::getline` would avoid the problem.

I won't comment on further occurrences of `std::cin >> ...` + `std::cin.clear();`.

---

```
    if (user_choice == 0)
    {
        if (comp_choice == 1) // Computer = Paper
        {
```

These `if`-`else if` chains with the same variable compared to different constants are better transformed into `switch` constructs. This way you'll

1. Avoid repetition of the variable name,
2. Make it easier to understand that a single variable is being tested for possible variants of values, not just many unrelated conditions are chained.

---

```
    if (user_choice == 0)
    ...
    if (user_choice == 1)
    ....
```

Instead of hard-coding numeric values, it's better to name them. E.g.

```
    enum : unsigned
    {
        CHOICE_ROCK=1,
        CHOICE_PAPER,
        CHOICE_SCISSOR,

        NUM_CHOICES
    };
```

You can then easily print the menu like

```
    for(unsigned c=CHOICE_ROCK;c<NUM_CHOICES;++c)
        std::cout << c << " for " << choice_names[c-1] << (c+1==NUM_CHOICES ? '\n' : '\t');
```

with the benefit that you can now reorder choices (in the enumeration and in `choice_names`), and the other code won't require changes (when you also fix `"Both " << user_name << " and Computer chooses SCISSOR\n"` so that it doesn't hard-code the `SCISSOR` string). This is known as the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY_principle).

---

```
void Game::exit_game()
{
    std::cout << "Thanks for playing!!\n";
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

In C++ it's better to avoid using `std::exit` (yes, it's in namespace `std`; its presence in global namespace [is not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32606023/673852) for `<cstdlib>`, unlike `<stdlib.h>`). The reason is that it doesn't call any destructors of automatic variables. In your case it doesn't matter much, since `class Game` doesn't need any real destruction, but generally you might lose some resources this way, since classes may use the [RAII idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) to e.g. grab and release external resources, and need to e.g. close USB devices, delete temporary files, say goodbye to a remote host etc..

---

`main.cpp`: the `<iostream>` include is not needed there.

---

```
int main()
{
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Nitpick: reaching the end of `main` function automatically returns 0, so this `return` statement is unnecessary. (Note that this only applies to `main`, not any other function.)

---

I won't repeat what the other answers say, please do read them: they make quite good points.

Comment: If I use `std::getline(std::cin, user_name)` it does not take any input and directly asks for `number_of_turns`

Comment: @coder right. This is because the input operation before it, via `operator>>`, got the number (`1` to Enter) and left the `'\n'` and any other characters after the number in the input buffer. You should call `std::cin.ignore()` before doing `std::getline` on `std::cin` to avoid this. Test case: instead of `1`, try entering `1 hello` in the first menu: you'll get ` hello\n` as the user name with current code + `getline`. Better yet way is to validate user input completely, by using `getline` everywhere and checking that there's no trailing garbage in the input.

Answer (score 8):

As you are asking for using more c++11 features specifically.

#### 1. Use raw string literals

The way you are printing your banner looks clunky, and is hard to maintain:

```
std::cout << "####  ####  ####  #  #   ####  ####  ####  ####  ####\n";
std::cout << "#  #  #  #  #     # #    #  #  #  #  #  #  #     #  #\n";
std::cout << "####  #  #  #     ##     ####  ####  ####  ####  ####\n";
std::cout << "# #   #  #  #     # #    #     #  #  #     #     # # \n";
std::cout << "#  #  ####  ####  #  #   #     #  #  #     ####  #  #\n";
std::cout << "\n\n";
std::cout << "   ####  ####  #  ####  ####  ####  ####\n";
std::cout << "   #     #     #  #     #     #  #  #  #\n";
std::cout << "   ####  #     #  ####  ####  #  #  ####\n";
std::cout << "      #  #     #     #     #  #  #  # # \n";
std::cout << "   ####  ####  #  ####  ####  ####  #  #\n";
std::cout << "\n\n";
```

IMO this can be done way better using a raw string literal like

```
std::string banner = R"x(
####  ####  ####  #  #   ####  ####  ####  ####  ####
#  #  #  #  #     # #    #  #  #  #  #  #  #     #  #
####  #  #  #     ##     ####  ####  ####  ####  ####
# #   #  #  #     # #    #     #  #  #     #     # # 
#  #  ####  ####  #  #   #     #  #  #     ####  #  #


   ####  ####  #  ####  ####  ####  ####
   #     #     #  #     #     #  #  #  #
   ####  #     #  ####  ####  #  #  ####
      #  #     #     #     #  #  #  # # 
   ####  ####  #  ####  ####  ####  #  #

)x";

std::cout << banner;
```

#### 2. Prefer Pseudo Number Generation over `rand()`

The functions and classes from the [Pseudo Number Generation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library, give you better control about the way the random numbers are generated:

- ability to use hardware devices for randomizing (e.g. based on cosmic radiation detection)
- ability to control the mean distribution of random numbers chosen

Answer (score 6):

Your game play function is excessively verbose.  You execute the **same lines of code** in 6 different places to print out the user & computer choices:

```
        std::cout << user_name << " chooses " << data[user_choice];
        std::cout << " and Computer chooses " << data[comp_choice] << "\n";
```

You could refactor this common code to one location:

```
    if ( user_choice != comp_choice ) {
        std::cout << user_name << " chooses " << data[user_choice];
        std::cout << " and Computer chooses " << data[comp_choice] << "\n";
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
```

You’ve got 3 different places where you print out the “Both choose” text.  You can refactor this into the else clause, by using the `data[]` array to print out what the selection was.

```
        std::cout << "Both " << user_name << " and Computer chooses " << data[user_choice] << "\n";
```

Finally, you’ve got 3 copies of user wins and 3 copies of player wins.  This again can be reduced to one copy each, with a suitable `if else` statement.  The player wins when they play a code 1 higher (mod 3) than the computer.  Place this code in the non-tie part of the above if statement:

```
        if ( (user_choice % 3) == ((comp_choice+1) % 3)) {
            std::cout << "----" << user_name << " Wins!!----\n";
            user_score++;
        } else {
            std::cout << "----Computer Wins!!----\n";
            comp_score++;
        }
```